# How to model objects with comparable fields in protobuf

Tags: protocol-buffers

Given 3 objects `A`, `B` and `C` where:

- `A` and `B` share a number of fields, but also each have unique fields
- all fields of both `A` and `B` are in `C`, which also some extra unique fields

Obviously I could model this in protobuf by creating separate messages for every object:

```
message A {
    uint32 A_B = 1;
    uint32 A_C = 2;
}

message B {
    uint32 A_B = 1;
    uint32 B_C = 2;
}

message C {
    uint32 A_B   = 1;
    uint32 A_C   = 2;
    uint32 B_C   = 3;
    uint32 onlyC = 4;
}
```

But I was wondering whether it makes sense to create a single, generic message for all three objects and add a field that tells me which specific object I'm dealing with?

```
message Generic {
    enum Specific{
        A = 1;
        B = 2;
        C = 3;
    }
    Specific obj = 1;
    uint32 A_B   = 2;
    uint32 A_C   = 3;
    uint32 B_C   = 4;
    uint32 onlyC = 5;
}
```

I know both options are possible from a technical point of view, but is the second one somehow not according to how things should be done in protobuf?

Note: in my specific case, the objects represent API call argument lists that won't change in the future.

Comment: If you *were* to do that, you might want to look at `oneof` - however, I guess the real question is: in the individual places when `A`, `B` or `C` are used: do you know which of them it is? or do you actually need to be able to handle all 3 in all cases?

Comment: The actual code will handle `A`, `B` and `C` differently, this only pertains to serialization.

Comment: I have already looked at `oneof` and that works when I want to merge `A` and `B`. Their unique fields are then declared using `oneof`. But with `C` in the mix that becomes more difficult because `C` wants both the unique fields of `A` and `B`, so not only one of them.

Comment: then: leave it alone IMO - it was already clearer and more meaningful at the usage sites, *and* more efficient (in terms of both serialization and object allocations) - or just have `C` *contain* an `A` and a `B`

Comment: @MarcGravell with leaving it alone, you mean use the first option (separate message for each object)?

Comment: sure; however, it is possible that there's context here that I'm not picking up from the question; ultimately all of them will work - so: if you like one, use that?